# A way to strsplit and replace all of one character with several variations of alternate strings?

Tags: r, stringr, strsplit

I am sure there is a simple solution and I am just getting too frustrated to work through it but here is the issue, simplified:

I have a string, ex: `AB^AB^AB^^BAAA^^BABA^`
I want to replace the `^s` (so, 7 characters in the string), but iterate through many variants and be able to retain them all as strings

for example:

- replacement 1: `CCDCDCD` to get: `ABCABCABDCBAAADCBABAD`
- replacement 2: `DDDCCCD` to get: `ABDABDABDCBAAACCBABAD`

I imagine `strsplit` is the way, and I would like to do it in a `for loop`, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The positions of the `"^"` can be found using `gregexpr`, see `tmp`

```
x <- "AB^AB^AB^^BAAA^^BABA^"
y <- c("CCDCDCD", "DDDCCCD")
tmp <- gregexpr(pattern = "^", text = x, fixed = TRUE)
```

You can then split the 'replacements' character by character using `strsplit`, this gives a list. Finally, iterate over that list and replace the `"^"` with the characters from your replacements one after the other.

```
sapply(strsplit(y, split = ""), function(i) {
  `regmatches<-`("AB^AB^AB^^BAAA^^BABA^", m = tmp, value = i)
})
```

Result

```
# [1] "ABCABCABCCBAAACCBABAC" "ABDABDABDDBAAADDBABAD"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a for loop. You can `strplit` your string and pattern, and then replace the `"^"` with the vector.

```r
str <- unlist(strsplit(str, ""))
pat <- unlist(strsplit("CCDCDCD", ""))

str[str == "^"] <- pat
paste(str, collapse = "")
# [1] "ABCABCABDCBAAADCBABAD"
```

Comment: because the modified characters came from the output of a previous string (I am iterating 100k times on a longer string), I kept it embedded in the loop, but this is exactly what I wanted to base my loop on; thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

An option is also with `gsubfn`

```
f1 <- Vectorize(function(str1, str2) {
     p <- proto(fun = function(this, x)  substr(str2, count, count))
     gsubfn::gsubfn("\\^", p, str1)         
         
     })
```

-testing

```
> unname(f1(x, y))
[1] "ABCABCABDCBAAADCBABAD" "ABDABDABDCBAAACCBABAD"
```

#### data

```
x <- "AB^AB^AB^^BAAA^^BABA^"
y <- c("CCDCDCD", "DDDCCCD")
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `x <- "AB^AB^AB^^BAAA^^BABA^"` and `y <- c("CCDCDCD", "DDDCCCD")`, we can try `utf8ToInt` + `intToUtf8` + `replace` like below

```
sapply(
  y,
  function(s) {
    intToUtf8(
      replace(
        u <- utf8ToInt(x),
        u == utf8ToInt("^"),
        utf8ToInt(s)
      )
    )
  }
)
```

which gives

```
                CCDCDCD                 DDDCCCD 
"ABCABCABDCBAAADCBABAD" "ABDABDABDCBAAACCBABAD"
```